# How do you convert several nested loops into lambda or linq when you have a complex object structure?

Tags: c#, linq, loops, lambda

I am running into trouble when trying to convert my multiple nested loops into a lambda or linq expression. I think I am having a hard time understanding how to properly access the properties when using the .All or .Contains methods. In any case, help is greatly appreciated. (I have read several other posts on this subject but am still struggling to make it work.)

**Here are what the classes look like:**

```
public class RecipeSearch
{
    public List<Recipe> Recipe { get; set; }
    public List<Meal> MealSettings { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> MainIngredient { get; set; }
}

public class Meal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

}

public class MainIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

**Here's the nested loop:**

```
IEnumerable<Recipe> recipeList = dbContext.Recipes
                .OrderBy(r => r.name)
                .Where(r => r.name.Contains(name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                .ToList();
//Model object is of type RecipeSearch
            IEnumerable<Meal> selectedMeals = model.MealSettings.Where(x => x.Value == true);
            IEnumerable<MainIngredient> selectedIngredients = model.MainIngredient.Where(x => x.Value == true);

    foreach (var selected in recipeList) //loop through the master list 
    {
        foreach (var item in selectedMeals) //loop through selected meal categories 
        {
            if (selected.mealCategoryId == item.Id) //passed the meal category check (i.e. it exists)
            {
                foreach (var ingredient in selectedIngredients) // selected master ingredients
                {
                    if (selected.Ingredients.Any(x => x.SubCategory.mainCategoryid == ingredient.Id))
                    {
                        recipe.Recipe.Add(selected);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I suppose it should be noted that the loop works completely as expected. I just think that it lambda/linq is more clean to read.

**EDIT: Here are the other objects:**

```
    public partial class Recipe
    {
        public Recipe()
        {
            Directions = new HashSet<Direction>();
            Images = new HashSet<Image>();
            Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
            Nutritions = new HashSet<Nutrition>();
            Ratings = new HashSet<Rating>();
        }

        public int recipeId { get; set; }

//Removed other properties that are not relevant

        public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

        public virtual MealCategory MealCategory { get; set; }

        public virtual RecipeStatus RecipeStatus { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Ingredient
{
    public int ingredientId { get; set; }

    public int? recipeId { get; set; }

    public int? subCategoryId { get; set; }

    public int measurementId { get; set; }

    public int amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }

}

public partial class SubCategory
{
    public SubCategory()
    {
        Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
    }

    public int subCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public int? mainCategoryid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    public virtual Maincategory Maincategory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to work out what your code is doing as 1) we don't know what Recipe class is and 2) As you use `var` keyword, we don't know what each of the object are.

Comment: @DavidG I've adjusted the code to address your comments. (Thanks!)

Comment: Why do you want to convert your code? If you are having trouble writing a LINQ query, changes are others will have trouble reading it. If your code is now functioning, why change it? LINQ is a beautiful construct, but it's not required to change all your code to LINQ.

Comment: @WouterdeKort I want to change it for two reasons - first, I think it is cleaner. More importantly, I want to learn.

Comment: Looking at the answer from @Farhad AliNoo I wouldn't agree it's always cleaner. However, learning is always good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
var query = from selected in receipeList
            join item in selectedMeals on selected.MealCategoryId equals item.Id
            where selected.Ingredients.Select(x => x.SubCategory.mainCategoryid.Value)
              .Intersect(selectedIngredients.Select(s => s.Id)).Count() > 0
            select selected;


foreach(var sel in query)
    recipe.Recipe.Add(sel);
```

I can't see where you are getting `recipe.Recipe` from though.

Basically in order to help you translate that into linq and adjust as you want:

This:

```
foreach (var selected in recipeList) //loop through the master list 
    {
        foreach (var item in selectedMeals) //loop through selected meal categories 
        {
            if (selected.mealCategoryId == item.Id) //passed the meal category check (i.e. it exists)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Translates into join like so:

```
from selected in receipeList
join item in selectedMeals on selected.MealCategoryId equals item.Id
```

Also, these lines:

```
if (selected.Ingredients.Any(x => x.SubCategory.mainCategoryid == ingredient.Id))
{
    recipe.Recipe.Add(selected);
    break;
}
```

Can be translated into:

```
where selected.Ingredients.Select(x => x.SubCategory.mainCategoryid.Value)
              .Intersect(selectedIngredients.Select(s => s.Id)).Count() > 0
select selected;
//and then
foreach(var sel in query)
    recipe.Recipe.Add(sel);
```

Comment: This is an amazing explanation! My first question is around the last piece (where selected.Ingredients.Any(x => selectedIngredients.Contains(x))). On the last piece I get this error: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RecipeTrackerMVC.Models.Search.Ingredient>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<RecipeTrackerMVC.Models.Ingredient>' Do I need to compare the id property of the models.Ingredient to the search.Ingredient? (The objects are different). Also, on query.ForEach I get an error saying that it does not contain a definition for 'ForEach'

Comment: @Yecats Oh yes I missed that they should be compared using their Ids there. I projected each ingredient in each sequence to their IDs. I also changed the code to use `Intersect` instead of two `Any` statements. Also the `ForEach` is only defined in `List<T>` not in `IEnumerable<T>` so I changed that to a normal `foreach`.

Comment: I've updated the code and I appear to be encountering an error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int?>' does not contain a definition for 'Intersect' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Intersect<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments. Also, what is the benefit with intersect vs. Any?

Comment: @Yecats That's strange because `Intersect` is contained in `IEnumerable<T>`. I can't see why it is complaining about a nullable type though(int?). Well the reason I used intersect is that you are basically comparing two different lists and you want to see if any item in one exists in the other. That is either done by two `Any` methods or the `Intersect`. I just thought that is cleaner and probably more efficient(if it does resort to hashing for faster operation).

Comment: I think the int? might be coming from my other ingredients class. I'm using entity framework (this is a website) and the recipe.Recipe is pointing towards the db object. That object has public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }. Then the Ingredient object has:         public int ingredientId { get; set; }
 ... well now I'm not sure where the int? is coming from. Does that help at all?

Comment: Oh I see. Well could you update the question with actual types in the foreach clauses instead of `var`? @Yecats

Comment: @Yecats I wander if projecting up to the actual int value of the nullable type would help. See my edit.

Comment: Looks like the .Value fixed it. I don't understand why that worked though? In any case, the last problem remaining is the ForEach 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RecipeTrackerMVC.Models.Recipe> does not contain a definition for 'ForEach'

Comment: @Yecats It seems like the types for source and target of intersect should match exactly so an `int` and `int?` was causing an issue. Yeah I've already changed that to a normal `ForEach`. See my answer.

Comment: Ok, I got around the foreach problem with the following:             recipe.Recipe = (from selected in recipeList
                        join item in selectedMeals on selected.mealCategoryId equals item.Id
                        where selected.Ingredients.Select(x => x.SubCategory.mainCategoryid.Value)
                          .Intersect(selectedIngredients.Select(s => s.Id)).Count() > 0
                        select selected).ToList();

Comment: @Yecats Yes. That works too. If this solved your problem please mark my answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following part,

```
IEnumerable<Recipe> recipeList = dbContext.Recipes
            .OrderBy(r => r.name)
            .Where(r => r.name.Contains(name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            .ToList();
```

2 things smell here:
First, you should swap the or-condition to check String.IsNullOrEmpty first, and
second put the where before the orderby to reduce items that need to be ordered.

```
IEnumerable<Recipe> recipeList = dbContext.Recipes               
            .Where(r => string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || r.name.Contains(name))
            .OrderBy(r => r.name)
            .ToList();
```

Depending on the ItemCount this might give you quite some "boost".